# Printing to USB Thermal printer with Python, Failed to open/win error: The device does not recognize the command

Tags: python, printing, usb, escpos

I am very new to Python and I cant seem to get a small script to run as intented.
Here is the code

```
from escpos.printer import Usb

p = Usb(0x0519, 0x0003)
p.text('Hello World!\n')
```

I got the code to run without the `p.text()` but when i try to send data to the printer with USB interface I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 236, in get_interface_and_endpoint
    return self._ep_info[endpoint_address]
KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    p.text('Hello World!\n')
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\escpos\escpos.py", line 506, in text
    self.magic.write(txt)
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\escpos\magicencode.py", line 244, in write
    self.write_with_encoding(encoding, to_write)
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\escpos\magicencode.py", line 263, in write_with_encoding
    self.driver._raw(
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\escpos\printer.py", line 99, in _raw
    self.device.write(self.out_ep, msg, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 986, in write
    intf, ep = self._ctx.setup_request(self, endpoint)
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 228, in setup_request
    intf, ep = self.get_interface_and_endpoint(device, endpoint_address)
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 238, in get_interface_and_endpoint
    for intf in self.get_active_configuration(device):
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 249, in get_active_configuration
    self.managed_open()
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 131, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 501, in open_device
    return _check(_lib.usb_open(dev))
  File "C:\Users\SSK\PycharmProjects\printer\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 447, in _check
    raise USBError(errmsg, ret)
usb.core.USBError: [Errno None] b'libusb0-dll:err [os_open] failed to open \\\\.\\libusb0-0001--0x0519-0x0003: win error: The device does not recognize the command.\r\n'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The printer I am using is a "Star TSP100", if anybody has any idea or suggestion I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: If you're a Star Micronics printer on a Windows OS, you shouldn't deal directly with the USB low-level protocol. Instead, set the printer to serial port mode, install the vendor's serial port device driver, and print in mode using Pyserial. It's the easiest and less likely to cause problems.

Comment: @kunif do you know how to send "Cutter control | ESC d | Paper cutter instruction" to the printer? the .cut() does not work

Comment: [ESC d](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=17) is a print and paper feed, not a paper cut. The paper cut will be [GS V](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=87).